# If the domain of a joint distribution density is restricted, is the domain of the marginal density restricted?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a joint distribution $f(x,y)$ and the domain is restricted such that $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$.

Suppose my marginal density function for $y$ is

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{2}{5}  + \frac{4}{5} y +  \frac{2}{5} y$$

Notice there are no $x$'s in the expression, but my joint distribution function depends on them.

Does the marginal density depend on $x$?

Comment: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution).

Comment: No.  That's the point of it being marginal.

Answer (score 1):

There are no $x$'s because the uncertainty due to the random variable $X$ has been marginalised away: $f_Y(y)$ is the marginal density with respect to the random variable $Y$.

If the joint density $f(x,y)=g(x,y){\bf 1}_{0<x<1}{\bf 1}_{0<y<1}$ for some appropriate function $g(x,y)$ then, in your case,

$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,y){\bf 1}_{0<x<1}\,\mathrm dx\right){\bf 1}_{0<y<1} =  \left(\frac25+\frac65y\right){\bf 1}_{0<y<1}
$$